# Why Can The Charge Distribution of A 2D Conductor Be Determined By Flattening Its 3D Counterpart?

Tags: electrostatics, conductors, method-of-images

The most famous instance of this trick is probably in the case of finding the surface charge distribution of a charged conducting disc, where this disc can be perceived as a squashed down version of a charged conducting sphere (which we know to be uniformly charged).

For the disc, we know that the charge of a ring at a distance $r$ and thickness $dr$ from its center is $\sigma(r) 2\pi r dr$, assuming the distribution only depends on $r$.
[image]

Meanwhile, this corresponds to two rings both at a polar angle of $\theta = sin^{-1}(r/R)$, and each with charge ${Q\over{4\pi R^2}} 2\pi R^2 sin\theta d\theta = {Q\over{2}\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}dr$.
[image]

As the sum of these two rings give the charge of the disc-ring, we have $\sigma(r) = {Q\over{2\pi R} \sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}$.

But... this is bizarre. I mean yes, intuitively it makes some sense, but it's a completely pulled-out-of-a-hat approach that is seemingly unrelated to restricting an area in space to be equipotential. I guess it shouldn't be surprising that the solution to the charge distribution of the disc is somehow geometrically related to the distribution of the sphere, but it seems ridiculous that any work using separation of variables etc. etc. can just be nullified with some simple geometry. If this works in general, can't we then also easily find the distribution of a neutral conducting disc with a point charge placed on its axis? More to the point, how do we know this method gives the correct solution in general? (If it doesn't work in general, in what cases does it work and in what cases does it not?)

[image]

(For reference, other examples of these "3D counterparts" would be: a rectangular plate corresponds to a squashed cylinder, a triangular one corresponds to a squashed cone, an ellipse would correspond to a squashed ellipsoid, etc. etc.)

Comment: "Pulled out of the hat" solutions are a common approach. You guess, and then verify that the solution actually works. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Well, that's the core of what I don't understand here, how do we verify that this method does give the right answer every time? I know there's a more rigorous approach in the case of the charged conducting disc on its own, but it doesn't seem like we could be as sure in the more complicated cases.

Comment: More complicated cases are, well, more complicated. In general, your only resort is numerical analysis. Textbook symbolic methods rarely work in real life.

Comment: So, it might not work for the case of the point charge and disc? The integrals that you'd have to perform to check the solution using the squashing method seem to be analytically unsolvable.

Comment: Surface charge distribution is a function of surface area. Squashing the sphere is morphing it into a two dimension planar surface with charge distributed evenly on both sides of the planar surface. It's similar to a deflated soccer ball.

Comment: I don't get how that explains the fact that squashing the sphere lets it retain its equipotential property though...

Comment: @davidaddisonsenjaya The set of analytically integrable functions has measure zero. Textbook writers give you unrealistic ideas by choosing their examples from this set.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you mean by 3D counterpart; You talked about a specific case whereby a uniformly charged sphere is flattened to a 2D version, which is a rather specific case and nothing to do with the assertion that this could work in general. You should provide citations as to where you got this assertion stated generally, and what is actually being said.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I guess I should provide more examples; a 2D rectangular strip could be seen as a deflated cylinder, a triangular plate could be seen as a flattened out cone, an ellipse would be, well, a squashed ellipsoid, etc. etc. Basically the solid of revolution of the 2D shape in question. I have little to no idea on whether or not this works in general, my teacher had used it to find the distribution for an infinite conducting strip placed in a uniform electric field, and he could not justify the method other than the fact that it was supposedly a common Olympiad trick.

Comment: @JohnDoty Well, alright then, more to the point, how would you have solved for the distribution in the case of the point charge and the disc then (or at least, how would you check whether or not the answer given by the "trick" is correct)?

Comment: @davidaddisonsenjaya I guess I'd simulate what happens in real life. Start with an arbitrary charge distribution, numerically compute the field, and let it drive the distribution to equilibrium.

Comment: @JohnDoty Okay, I'd like to check the solutions numerically myself then. What program do you use to compute the field?

Comment: @davidaddisonsenjaya Don't know of a program, guess I'd code it in Mathematica. I use NEC2 for full-up electrodynamics of conductive structures (antennas), but it doesn't do electrostatics.